# Detect user selection from Spinner in mvvmcross

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross

In the following code, I could able to display the `CategoryList` items in the spinner.

My question, how could I able to detect which one is chosen?

**ViewModel.cs**

```
public List<int> CategoryList
{
  get { return new List<int> { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 }; }
}

int _chosenCategory; 
public int ChosenCategory { 
   get { return _chosenCategory; } 
   set { SetProperty(ref _chosenCategory, value); 
  } 
}
```

**ViewModel.axml**

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_width="0dp"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.appcompat.widget.MvxAppCompatSpinner
         android:layout_width="100dp"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/xxx"
         local:MvxBind="ItemsSource CategoryList;SelectedItem ChosenCategory" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: using [Sven-Michael Stübe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058772/detect-user-selection-from-spinner-in-mvvmcross#answer-37059047) answer, try updating your `ChosenCategory` property to fire the `INotifyPropertyChanged` e.g. `int _chosenCategory; public int ChosenCategory { get { return _chosenCategory; } set { SetProperty(ref _chosenCategory, value); } }`

Comment: it did not work as well. it does not call `set` method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can bind it via `SelectedItem`

```xml
<mvvmcross.droid.support.v7.appcompat.widget.MvxAppCompatSpinner
     android:layout_width="100dp"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     local:MvxItemTemplate="@layout/category_spinner"
     local:MvxBind="ItemsSource CategoryList; SelectedItem ChosenCategory" />
```

And ensure that you have this in you Setup class:

```cs
public class Setup : MvxAndroidSetup
{
    // ...

    protected override void FillTargetFactories(IMvxTargetBindingFactoryRegistry registry)
    {
        MvxAppCompatSetupHelper.FillTargetFactories(registry);
        base.FillTargetFactories(registry);
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you have not set up the app compat library correctly. I added the setup code to the answer.

Comment: I have the following in the `FillTargetFactories` method  `registry.RegisterFactory(new MvxCustomBindingFactory<MvxAppCompatSpinner>("MyItemSelected", view => new MyItemSelectedBinding(view)));`

Comment: What does `MyItemSelectedBinding` do?

Comment: I'd use the official one, but if you need your own one: go for it :)

Comment: You mean the following?      `local:MvxBind="ItemsSource CategoryList; MyItemSelected ChosenCategory" />`

Comment: Look at my answer. This is working. No idea what `MyItemSelected` is and does.